# How to redraw StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

On the example below, since `MyStatefulWidget` has a state, it doesn't matter if `setState` is called on `_MyAppState`, because it will not be redrawn.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Example')),
        body: Row(children:[
          MyStatefulWidget(title: value.toString()), 
          RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){setState(() { value+=1; });},
            child: new Text("Add"),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.title}):super(key: key);
  final String title;
  
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyStatefulWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String title;
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.title!=null) {
      title = widget.title;
    } else {
      title = "";
    }
  }
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(title);
  }
}
```

If I used a `StatelessWidget` it'd be redrawn, but this is just an example, there are cases where I need to redraw a `StatefulWidget` when `setState` is called.

One option would be to give it a name and build it from the setState, but I need it to be draw in the place where it's draw right now.

Dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/968be8755d5deab1ca5c8c84a993eafc

Comment: The question isn't clear. The answer by @bluenile is correct, but is seems like you want to achieve something different than what you're asking.

Comment: edit the question to be very clear about the result and what has been tried till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use widget.title in the Text widget to update the counter on screen. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void changeVal(int val) {
    setState(() {
      value = val;
    });
  }

  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('App Example')),
        body: Row(children: [
          MyStatefulWidget(
              title: value.toString(),
              groupValue: value % 10,
              chnageVal: changeVal),
          RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                value += 1;
              });
            },
            child: const Text("Add"),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.title, this.groupValue, this.chnageVal})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final int groupValue;
  final Function(int) chnageVal;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyStatefulWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  //String title;
  // @override
  // void initState() {
  // super.initState();
  // if (widget.title!=null) {
  //   title = widget.title;
  // } else {
  //  title = "";
  // }
  // }
  //int value = 0;

  List<int> numbers = List.generate(10, (index) => index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      child: Column(children: [
        Text(widget.title),
        ...numbers
            .map((number) => RadioListTile<int>(
                  title: Text('$number'),
                  value: number,
                  groupValue: widget.groupValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    widget.chnageVal(val);
                  },
                ))
            .toList()
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This was just an example. Suppose that instead of a text, the `MyStatefulWidget` was a radio group. The `MyStatefulWidget` itself can change the radio group state, but I also want to be able to set the radio group from the parent

Comment: I've updated the code. I've added a Radio group of 10 RadioListTile with value 0 to 9. Now every time you tap the `Add` button the `Text` widget will be updated with `value` just as it did previously. However depending on the last digit of the `value` the radio group will also be updated.

Comment: The main problem is that you're still reading `widget.groupValue`, I cannot do that because the radio widget (`MyStatefulWidget` in your case), should be able to alter the selected radio button when one is clicked. So we cannot use `widget.groupVale`, which is const.

Comment: I opened a bounty, please take a look

Comment: Updated the code, now you can click a Radio button and the value of the Radio button will become the value of the Text. So the value is being passed back.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a unique key while calling `MyStatefulWidget` like `MyStatefulWidget(key: UniqueKey(), title: value.toString()),`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Example')),
        body: Row(children: [
          MyStatefulWidget(key: UniqueKey(), title: value.toString()),
          RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                value += 1;
              });
            },
            child: new Text("Add"),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyStatefulWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String title;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.title != null) {
      title = widget.title;
    } else {
      title = "";
    }
  }

  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(title);
  }
}
```

To know more about key please go through [this](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/keys-in-flutter-104fc01db48f) article.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using Stream, better performance and not so hard to use for refresh partial UI.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _MyAppState();
      }
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
StreamController<int> _streamController = StreamController();
      int value = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: 
StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        initialData: value,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Example')),
            body: Row(children:[
              MyStatefulWidget(title: value.toString()), 
              RaisedButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: (){_streamController.sink.add(value++);},
                child: new Text("Add"),
              )
            ]),
          );},),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.title}):super(key: key);
      final String title;
      
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _MyStatefulWidgetState();
      }
    }
    
    class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
      String title;
       @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        if (widget.title!=null) {
          title = widget.title;
        } else {
          title = "";
        }
      }
      int value = 0;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text(title);
      }
    }
```